# can logstash send data simultaneusly to mulpile location along with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Normally, in ELK logstash parsed data and send to elastics search.

I want to know is it possible that logstash send same data to different location at real time.

If it is possible, please let me know how to do it.

Comment: What did you found so far?

Comment: logstash can take input from 48 diffrent way and can send output to different location as well..but my concerned can it send simultaneusly to different location.

Comment: Simply use several outputs, and Logstash will send your data to each listed output

Answer (score 0):

Create several output files that match type and send to different hosts.

```
output {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
          index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
          codec => "plain"
          workers => 1
          manage_template => true
          template_name => "logstash"
          template_overwrite => false
          flush_size => 100
          idle_flush_time => 1
    }
  }
}
```